# fetch core data base64 image string and display in tableview swift 2.0

Tags: swift2

I am working on swift 2.0 project with core data .I want to save my picker image in core data.I am converting my image into base64 string.

I want to decode my image

```
//here Iam creating instance for core data to get image  
let image1 = dbsingle.valueForKey("task_image")as?String
//Iam decoding like this
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: image1 , options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
var decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData)
print(decodedData)//I am getting null'
```

Comment: So why are you converting to base-64?

Comment: i need to send the image to the server as string formate i have to save the save formate in core data also

Comment: And so everything must be encoded the same way?

Comment: yes.i save the image to core data  as a string

Comment: only image i have to encode.